# How to upload two deobfuscationfiles for one APK using androidpublisher?

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-play-developer-api, androidpublisher

Is it possible to upload "ReTrace mapping file" and "Native debug symbols" simultaneously for a single APK?

We use "androidpublisher_v3" from [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) npm package ("googleapis": "^70.0.0") in our application and we manage to publish a new APK with one deobfuscation file (mapping.txt OR native-debug-symbols.zip) to the Google Play Console.

Our current flow is:

1. Initializing Google Play publisher API.
2. Creating a new edit transaction in Google Play.
3. Uploading APK
4. Uploading mapping.txt file
5. Committing the edit transaction in Google Play.

We have a function for uploading mapping.txt file (which uses [Method: edits.deobfuscationfiles.upload](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.deobfuscationfiles/upload)):

```js
/**
 * Uploads a deobfuscation file (mapping.txt) for a given package
 * Assumes authorized
 * @param {string} mappingFilePath the path to the file to upload
 * @param {string} packageName unique android package name (com.android.etc)
 * @param apkVersionCode version code of uploaded APK
 * @returns {Promise} deobfuscationFiles A promise that will return result from uploading a deobfuscation file
 *                          { deobfuscationFile: { symbolType: string } }
 */
export async function uploadDeobfuscation(edits: any, mappingFilePath: string, packageName: string, apkVersionCode: number): Promise<void> {
    const requestParameters = {
        deobfuscationFileType: 'proguard',
        packageName: packageName,
        apkVersionCode: apkVersionCode,
        media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream(mappingFilePath),
            mimeType: ''
        }
    };

    try {
        const res = (await edits.deobfuscationfiles.upload(requestParameters)).data;
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(tl.loc('CannotUploadDeobfuscationFile', mappingFilePath, e));
    }
}
```

And also we have almost the same function to upload native-debug-symbols.zip (the only difference is another deobfuscationFileType: nativeCode)

So if we call *edits.deobfuscationfiles.upload* once to upload one of the deobfuscation files it works fine, but if we want to upload mapping.txt and native-debug-symbols with a single *edits* transaction, we can only see the last file uploaded to the Google Play Console (App bundle explorer -> Downloads -> Assets)
[Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3H7l.png)
[Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNVVD.png)

Is it expected behavior?

---

Also, I was able to reproduce this with the **.Net** client library (NuGet package:  [AndroidPublisher.v3/1.51.0.2239](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3/1.51.0.2239?_src=template))

---